# case statement for converting to date in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.4

```
case when  to_date(substring(data,126,8), 'YYYYMMDD') = '00000000' or to_date(substring(data,126,8), 'YYYYMMDD') = '20180505' or to_date(substring(data,126,8), 'YYYYMMDD') = ''
    then null
    else
         to_date(substring(data,126,8), 'YYYYMMDD')
    end  ,
      trim( substring(data,126,8))
```

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "00000000" LINE 15: ...hen
>   to_date(substring(data,126,8), 'YYYYMMDD') = '00000000'...

sample data in my file is like:

```
20180704
  28.08  
  65.48  
  74.98  
  93.87  
20180705
```